# Remove + from Telephone in Contact Form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to remove + from contact form 7 telephone field while submitting the form. The form should be submitted without + in telephone field.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add CSS rule then set off symbol if is icon like:

```
[text text-123 id:very-special-field]
```

If is simple character you must find code in any file of plugin.

Comment: No, I want to let users enter them there.

Comment: You can use this solution so:[LINK](http://techiescircle.com/validate-telephone-field-length-contact-form-7/)